# Can we remove tag names in question title

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic removal of bracketed tags from question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-bracketed-tags-from-question-titles)

as i see, many questions will be posted with tagnames, even though question already tagged with particular langauge/framework/tools..etc. why we cant remove those taganme from the question title 
for eg: How to add user control on run time in ASP.NET? 
can be replaced with

```
How to add user control on run time
```

may be it will help, so that editing will be less.