# Automatically remove the patterns "tag :" and "tag -" from titles

Tags: feature-request, title, automatic-edits

My [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is a, slightly, stricter version of [this, un-actioned one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them).

If the following conditions are true, can the patterns be automatically be removed from the question title:

1. Where the pattern `^<tag>\s?(-|:)\s?` is matched.
2. The question has *actually* been tagged with the `<tag>` matched in the pattern.

If the tag is hyphenated, then spaces, should be deemed to be hyphens, for instance `ruby on rails:` should match `ruby-on-rails`

Basically, I'm agreeing with Tomalak's comment on [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105991/179419) to the looser feature request.

###The argument

1. A while back [Jeff approved the removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100492/179419) of the pattern
   `^\[[^]]+\]\s` at the start of titles to remove pseudo-tags; as there "were a ton - around 20-25k"

   The pattern `<tag>:` matches [120k questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/74290/question-titles-with-the-pattern-tag) and the pattern
   `<tag>-` matches [98k questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/74291/question-titles-with-the-pattern-tag). These are far higher volumes than prompted Jeff's
   original change, though obviously there are now more questions.
2. The [FAQ states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) that:

   > it is completely unnecessary to force tags into your question title

   Can't argue with that!
3. Back in 2010 Jeff said:

   > To be clear, I think it is fine to duplicate the tags in the title,
   > but only when they can be worked into the titles organically and
   > conversationally.

   Neither of these patterns can be said to qualify on this count. They are obviously just tags prepended to a title.
4. Because we're insisting on the existence of a hyphen or semi-colon there's no danger of accidentally matching something like [Java Synchronization Not Working as Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982941/java-synchronization-not-working-as-expected). But, the needless "Java:" at the front of [Java: Can creating an object “return” a null reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103444/java-can-creating-an-object-return-a-null-reference) gets trashed.
5. The amount of questions that start `mysql -` or `python:` is really annoying.

Comment: I wonder how often the tag is added long after the question is posted, though. In other words, it isn't always the case that matching on a tag can happen when the question is created. I do my best to edit a title when the tag is there, but I bet I miss a lot of questions in the tags I follow because they weren't initially tagged correctly.

Comment: So you want some kind of trigger when a tag is added?

Comment: But don't those happen only when the question is created?

Comment: I don't understand. You tried changing the title to `title Automatically ...`? And it removed the `title` prefix? And this doesn't happen if you try `title :` or `title -`? Can you please be explicit about what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: I'm suggesting adding those filters. I tried editing it to `[tag] title` and the SE system wouldn't let me; there was an error message, try it yourself. I'm suggesting doing this automatically admittedly, as it's just superfluous information.

Comment: What error message? I was able to edit it fine (although I don't have enough rep on meta.SO for it to not require waiting for peer approval).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you added `title` not `[tag]`, the point being the square brackets as per the linked posts. The error message is: "Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
title contains a [tag] prefix; please use the tag field to enter tags instead.". I'm deleting my earlier comments so this doesn't get too long.

Comment: If your question was tagged `sql-server` I would have added `SQL Server` to the beginning of the question title. Not `[tag]`...

Comment: You mean _removed_, by your comments under Rosinante's answer? If so I'm proposing removing that `SQL Server:` from the beginning of the title.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you're following my line of thought or actions at all. I'm going to leave it at this: I agree with you. I don't have patience for mental Olympics today.

Comment: title: `"http://example.com is deemed not valid by my proxy"` tags: "[tag:http] [tag:proxy]". Removing `http:` would be disastrous here.

Comment: Removing _just_ http would be disastrous, it wouldn't matter if http:// was removed. Unless it is actually example.com I can't imagine anything with that title being a very good question @jan. Isn't it the definition of too localized? (just realised you're mainly active on SO where this should also be off-topic really).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I'm not saying it's a good question. More like "one of the ton of 'plz help debug my codez' questions that don't get closed despite most likely not being helpful to anyone". If it's well asked, it won't even gather (many) downvotes. Admittably, a language tag is missing here.

Comment: **Opposed.** *unnecessary* != *forbidden*

Answer (score 4):

A question title should give a good preliminary sense of what the question is about. If starting with *one of the* tags has that effect, I'm in favor. I hate having to read a wall of question of go digging for the tags just to see what on earth the question is about. I am opposed.

Comment: I gathered :-). I'd counter by saying that you don't need to read a wall. They're on the line below the title... or are you thinking about a different situation?

Comment: The tags are visible in the question list views, and the most "important" tag is added to the page's title when viewing that question. That info's available already, adding it at the start of the title is just noise IMO.

Comment: It's more cognitive work to mentally mush in the separate tags. What is the harm in leaving one in the title?

Comment: @Rosinante when I come to a question because it's tagged `sql-server`, having to read past a leading `SQL Server` in the title is redundant and also, I would argue, "mental mush." There's no reason for it being there.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I don't come from the tag. I'm scanning the unanswered questions. So I don't know how to resolve our conflicting views.

Comment: You're scanning unanswered questions in any technology?

Comment: If you are reading a question title in the list of unanswered question and it sounds interesting to you, is it really that much more work to check the tags that are listed right under the question? That is less work than trying to piece together a poorly-worded question anyway - if I see the tags below the title and it's Java or PHP or Android I don't even bother (I don't know what "wall" you mean). Anyway, we don't need to resolve our conflicting views. I can just disagree with your "solution" to leave things as they are, since I don't think a Java question prefixed with "Java" helps anyone.

Comment: I have a lot of tags that I watch. I find that new askers generally make such a mess of their tag usage that filtering by tag doesn't have much useful effect at all.

Comment: Well given that many folks will help the user by editing the tag out of the title and tagging it correctly, and that some users do it correctly anyway, I don't think that relying on the tag being in the title instead of the tag being correct is very useful either.

Comment: I'm not 'relying' on it. I'm just finding it unobstrusive and sometimes helpful. You have the opposite reaction. The team will be the ultimate arbiter.

Answer (score 3):

We don't want to make the system any more confusing than it has to be. We should be simplifying it at this point, not adding additional complexity. That said, I think this could get us a net gain in quality *if paired with some additional efforts on that front*.

Getting people to write good, descriptive and clear titles is hard. Yet, the quality and clarity of your title does tend to determine the ultimate fate of your question:

- You get the title right, but 'meh' in the question - people *edit*.
- You get the title wrong, *and* 'meh' in the question - people *close*.

There's a whole lot of 'meh', unfortunately, and without a clear title to realize what you're talking about, you might as well be muttering gibberish.

> Android code not working

... >_<

> php mysql error in code

... Aaaaaagggggghhhhh! #DIE

So, what we did was expand our current blacklist to also *warn* instead of block, selectively. We put in a pattern to match, tell the system where to look for it (title, body, tags) and pop up some very custom just-in-time help for folks asking their first few questions.

It makes an *insane* amount of sense to have the ability to trip on any major tag here, if only to tell folks "Hey, people will know this is about Android by the tags. Use the extra space in your title to better summarize your problem"

I'm going to get with a few folks to find out if it's possible and economical to *warn* if you do this, and strongly encourage you to revise the title. It won't block, mind you - but I'm good with that for reasons others have expressed above.

Comment: And who knows, we may be able to take 'problem' out of the blacklist finally, if this works the way I think (and hope) it will. No promises on this yet, but I am going to bring it up on a feature call.

Comment: So, we are a bunch of goats, going "Meh, meh, meh, meeh!" Noted.

Comment: BTW, "what we did was expand our current blacklist" so, was this implemented or just "something similar"? What build should I hunt?

Comment: Still no love??

Comment: Is this love..?

Answer (score 1):

StackExchange sites, and especially SO, already have quite a few rules and unspoken practices that are hard enough for new users to learn. Lets not impose another rule, even if its just an automatic edit of the title the OP chooses. While it may not be necessary to include tag terms in question titles, neither is it currently prohibited. People should be free to use whatever title they like, provided that its appropriate to the question.

There are currently around **36,000** tags on SO! It often happens that people include tagged terms in the title simply because they don't realize that a tag exists for that term, and someone else adds the tag later. Reading past a term in a title is *not* an undue burden, so lets not add to the long list of SO rules.