# Warn about inclusion of unnecessary tags in question titles at the time of posting

Tags: feature-request, tags, title, posting

This search will reveal a ton of questions with `c#` in their title, which are also already tagged as [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23):

[[c#] is:question title:c#](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aquestion+title%3Ac%23)

Currently there are **93,199** such questions. In rare cases it may be important to leave that in the title, as it makes a difference, but mostly it's redundant use of tags.

SE rules [explicitly discourage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) the use of tags in question titles without good reasons, yet there is no pop-up message when there are tags detected in question title, which is kind of strange.

I see there is already [automatic removal of tags in brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-bracketed-tags-from-question-titles), but not in braces, or without any kind of separation. So there are still tons of questions when the use of tags in titles is redundant. In some cases, though, it's fine to include them in the title, like when otherwise the title won't make sense.

I propose to create automatic tag detection in question titles in form of a blue pop-up balloon with a link to the rules section about unnecessary inclusion of tags into question titles, reminding the poster to make sure it's absolutely necessary to have tags in the title.

**UPD**: I just found out there might already be a system that detects tags in question titles, as per [this comment from 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title?rq=1#comment175376_72694). I bet that could be used to activate a notification saying "*Make sure you're using tags in title correctly*".

Comment: I'd propose inline title editing, so script kiddies can userscript those bastards away.

Comment: @Won't That encourages people making minor edits, which get annoying when a lot of questions get bumped just to remove a tag from the title without fixing anything else.

Comment: Your proposal isn't quite the same as what's implied in your title...

Comment: Rather than bumping thousands of post @ Won't, just [automagically strip out the worst offenders](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138321/automatically-remove-the-patterns-tag-and-tag-from-titles)

Comment: @Servy: What can I say?  Don't bump on a title edit?  IDGAF.  And people edit only titles all the damned time, so there really isn't any reason not to afford inline edits for titles.

Comment: @Won't I'm saying it's annoying enough as is, this would make it even more annoying.

Comment: @Servy: I'm saying [meta-tag:feature-request] making it not annoying rather than not making it easier to fix titles.

Comment: @Won't I think what you propose is an option to edit a post without bumping it. Like a checkbox for high rep users maybe. But that has its own downsides too, like some users may wrongly uncheck bumping when the question *should* be bumped, but that's another question. Also it's better (and often easier) to prevent a fire than fighting it.