# Raising awareness for improper use of tags in titles, where they are not part of a full sentence

Tags: discussion, title

Check out these search results:

> [is:question title:" - "](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20title%3a%22%20-%20%22)

A significant portion of results are questions with titles that have a tag that stands separately from the rest of the title. Having tags in question titles is only okay if they're a part of a full sentence. If you see an example of incorrect inclusion of tags in titles, please edit the title accordingly*.

*<sub>I'm not telling you exactly how, because that isn't up to me to decide. For guidance, see this FAQ post: [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)</sub>

Comment: So your "question" is "here's a query that returns questions that probably need editing, help me fix them."  Or are you suggesting that titles including " - " be automatically acted on in some way?

Comment: The horror! Look at all those people using hyphens (-) where an em-dash (—) might be more appropriate!  I'll start replacing them! ;)

Comment: @blahdiblah I'm not asking anything, except the users to take note of such misuses and make edits.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I guess you're right, but then not all users have typographic keyboard layouts installed, like some advanced users, who might already know it's not cool to do that with tags. Okay, that was a joke. I honestly don't know anymore when people are not being serious on the internet.

Comment: @user1306322 I'm just poking fun;  I edit a _lot_ of these in the tags I'm active in.  People seem to think that Common Lisp and Scheme being prefix languages mean that everything should be prefixed with with "Common Lisp:" and "Scheme:". :(

Answer (score 6):

Out of the first page of 50 in the results you linked, there are maybe 2 or 3 question titles that *could* do with a tidy up, but they don't *need* a tidy up. This would indicate that the problem you've illustrated is not really that much of a problem. These are not the titles of people trying to seed keywords, they are the titles of people thinking about their question in a categorical way.

StackOverflow already has some parsing for obvious tags in titles, and I think your suggestion is rather tenuous and prone to false positives. In any case, it would only be a matter of time before people switched to using a colon or semi-colon instead of the hyphen.

Comment: Why would they do that? If there is something removing the tags from titles (automation or people), then there must be a reason for that. Not long after the poster thinks that, they'll figure out the reason and will stop trying to include the tags into titles (if for whatever reason they were convinced this was the right thing to do).

Comment: Also I just changed the search request to show newest questions, not most relevant ones. There are many more "hits" now. Out of 50 newest, I counted 32 obvious cases of misuse.

Comment: @user1306322 Your search results do show more questionable titles now, but I still think your suggestion would be prone to false positives and easily circumvented. This is one reason why we have a large community with edit privileges - they can see these titles and correct them (of course that doesn't mean they always get done).

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I'm not suggesting to create an automated detection and removal script in this post, but check out [my other related post here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202032/warn-about-inclusion-of-unnecessary-tags-in-question-titles-at-the-time-of-posti). I'm just asking users to take action if they see improper use of tags in question titles, that is all.

Comment: @user1306322 While removing tags from titles is nice when you see it, there are so many more productive uses for your time than going out and actively searching for tags in titles to remove them.  Spend some time in the review queues working on *real* problematic content, or find queries that find problems that allow you to turn a terrible question into an acceptable question, rather than one that has only a marginal change on the quality of a question, and finds mostly questions that are already acceptable.

Comment: @Servy that search was just to show how often this happens, and so if you happen to come across such an example, I urge you to do something about it. Regarding review queues, I can't seem to get anything awaiting my reviews ever. I remember reviewing some questions about a year ago, but now there just aren't any.

Comment: @user1306322 Yes, it happens a lot.  All you need to look at the questions list anytime, pretty much ever, to see that it happens a lot.  It gets fixed a lot too, but that still doesn't mean it's a valuable investment of your time to go around looking for tags in titles to remove them.  You're even consuming a whole bunch of reviewers' time when you suggest such minor edits to fix them.  Find posts with *real* problems and really make them a lot better.  It's a much better use of your time and everyone else's as well.