# Bracketed tags in question titles: The Return

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, title

This has been a long time coming, people have found a workaround to the [automatic removal of bracketed tags in question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-bracketed-tags-from-question-titles): with *spaces*.

For example: [Handling AsyncCallback [ GWT ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115589/handling-asynccallbackt-gwt)

Now, the question is: what is to be done with that?

Comment: Edit them...? I don't see a problem here

Comment: @Doorknob I'm just reporting the issue. There's a feature, it's being circumvented.

Comment: Okay, so? People do that all the time. What's the problem? Just edit them out.

Comment: @Doorknob I won't edit them out, you edit them out. :) Seriously, it was a suggestion from the poster of the original question about bracketed tags to make a new question for this case.

Comment: If you don't want to edit them out, you must not think they're that big of a problem, then...

Comment: @Doorknob as the problem has been fixed in the past, all that is needed is a tweak to the code or solution that was implemented at Jeff's behest here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100492/146015

Comment: @Doorknob I keep track of several tags because they are prime targets for miss-tagging. I'm currently going through [tag:like]. Because that thing is manual. I'm a coder, just like you. If I see a task's that's repetitive, I stop and think "Hmmm, maybe this can be scripted." It's also not a problem to *me*, but I'm bringing it up because it might be a problem to the *community*.

Comment: Declining for pretty much the reasons that [animuson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221254/140505) gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why this has received a somewhat lukewarm (bordering on frosty) reception, as a specific fix was implemented for this some time ago, and now some people have worked out a way around it. All that should be required is to adjust the regex that is used to validate titles so that this warning reappears:

[image]

While these tags can be edited out it would be desirable to catch them before the question is submitted - removing redundant fluff like seeded tags in the title helps raise the quality of the question.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't something we should be worrying about. There will always be people who try to circumvent the system in weird ways, and blocking one way will just cause them to try another. Some people are just more dedicated to bypassing a restriction than just following the advice of the restriction to improve their post. We can't account for *every* possibility, but we can catch the *most common* one and inform users not to do that. Hopefully, they'll take the advice.