# Automatically remove tags that are at the beginning of titles

Tags: feature-request, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we prevent titles with an unnecessary tag in them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them)

I find myself "untagging" titles a lot. For example, a question that is tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) might have the title:

> Java: Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError?

Would it be possible for that tag reference to be automatically removed from the title? **I would think it only makes sense if the title begins with the tag, as removing words from the title itself probably isn't a good idea.** My only concern would be false postivies such as:

> Java doesn't have feature X

So maybe only remove tags from titles when they are followed by a colon, comma, dash, etc?

Comment: I think you mean that you want that text **edited out of the title**... untagging will result in a tagless post :)

Comment: Yes. I refer to "editing a tag out of a title" as "untagging a title".

Comment: If you do that though, then the title of this post would be "Automatically edit out of titles", and that wouldn't make much sense now, would it?

Comment: @casperOne, I specifically mentioned the tag as a prefix of the title.

Comment: I don't think "prefix" is the right word here...

Comment: Why not? Anyway, I revised my question.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler It was a joke.

Comment: @casperOne: Ah, fair enough :-P